# ROR send email heroku, gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I managed to configure ActionMailer on my local machine to send emails via Gmail. (it required tlsmail in gemfile)

```
### config/environment.rb
require 'tlsmail'

Ideas::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port           => '587',
    :domain         => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    :user_name      => 'xxxx@gmail.com', 
    :password       => 'xxxxxxx',
    :authentication => :plain
  }
end
```

This worked on my local machine (the emails were sent) but as usually hreoku had some problems with this (Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2))). I googled that they have a particular solution for gmail:

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/11/9/tech_sending_email_with_gmail/

They are saying I need an additional SMTP TLS library. As mentioned above I added a gem that resolved the issue but only on my local machine. Well ok, I tried their solution and it worked... on heroku, but stopped working on my local. (it doesn't give an error, it just says the email was sent, but it never is.)

Environmental variables are set properly.

Do you have any ideas how to make at least one of this methods work both on my local machine and heroku?

Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set it up in the correct environment. You'll need to do this in your gemfile with groups

```
group :development do
  gem '<development gem here>'

group :production do
  gem '<production gem here>'
```

Don't forget to rebundle. Then move the config relevant to each environment into either config/environments/production.rb or config/environments.development.rb

Comment: There still is a problem. What heroku makes me install isn't a gem. It's a plugin and I rather can't exclude it from a production version - or at least I don't know how. Even if I leave my configuration untouched this plugin overwrites it.

Comment: is there any reason you can't use the Sendgrid add on??

Comment: My account must be verified, so I have to give my credit card number, but I don't have one. :P