# Secure use of gmail and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, email, heroku

On this post here: [ROR send email heroku, gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976105/ror-send-email-heroku-gmail) it there is information on how to set up gmail with a heroku app. However, storing your gmail password as a plain text (see the question) is, I think, insecure. Does anyone know if one can use gmail with a heroku app with a FIX for this security?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store it in an environment varaible with `heroku config:add GMAIL_USER=name` and GMAIL_PASSWORD=password, then pull them out with ENV['GMAIL_USER'] etc.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Very. We use environment variables expressly for this sort of per-app storage of credentials. When you add an addon to your app, the credentials get added as env vars, as well as the user/pass for your database.

Comment: hey Will, I was wondering - this works great. BUT, how can I make these variables available on a localhost (for testing)

Comment: jay, use foreman. It supports a .env file—just make sure to add .env to your gitignore. It should not be checked in. http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/#ENVIRONMENT

Comment: sorry, it's been a long time.. you mean to use foreman to define these variables on a localhost?