# Rails untracked files to Heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy a rails app to heroku, and I know that their file system is read only, and it only contains the latest code. I am using a git repository, via [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git). I have a config file, holding passwords and other stuff that I don't want to track on git, but I have to upload them to heroku. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than store the confidential info in the app files, set them up as environment variables    on heroku using [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7832040/429758